# Field getter/setter with expression tree in base class

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees, setter, fieldinfo

Following the examples on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321650/how-do-i-set-a-field-value-in-an-c-sharp-expression-tree) and [its follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320500/how-do-i-generate-a-compiled-lambda-with-method-calls), I am trying to create field getters / setters using compiled expressions.

The getter works just great, but I am stuck the setter, as I need the setter to assign any type of fields.

Here my setter-action builder:

```
public static Action<T1, T2> GetFieldSetter<T1, T2>(this FieldInfo fieldInfo) {
  if (typeof(T1) != fieldInfo.DeclaringType && !typeof(T1).IsSubclassOf(fieldInfo.DeclaringType)) {
    throw new ArgumentException();
  }
  ParameterExpression targetExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "target");
  ParameterExpression valueExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "value");
  //
  // Expression.Property can be used here as well
  MemberExpression fieldExp = Expression.Field(targetExp, fieldInfo);
  BinaryExpression assignExp = Expression.Assign(fieldExp, valueExp);
  //
  return Expression.Lambda<Action<T1, T2>> (assignExp, targetExp, valueExp).Compile();
}
```

Now, I store the generic setters into a cache list (because of course, building the setter each time is a performance killer), where I cast them as simple "objects":

```
 // initialization of the setters dictionary
 Dictionary<string, object> setters = new Dictionary(string, object)();
 Dictionary<string, FieldInfo> fldInfos = new Dictionary(string, FieldInfo)();
 FieldInfo f = this.GetType().GetField("my_int_field");
 setters.Add(f.Name, GetFieldSetter<object, int>(f); 
 fldInfos.Add(f.Name, f); 
 //
 f = this.GetType().GetField("my_string_field");
 setters.Add(f.Name, GetFieldSetter<object, string>(f); 
 fldInfos.Add(f.Name, f);
```

Now I try to set a field value like this:

```
 void setFieldValue(string fieldName, object value) {
      var setterAction = setters[fieldName];
      // TODO: now the problem => how do I invoke "setterAction" with 
      // object and fldInfos[fieldName] as parameters...?
 }
```

I could simply call a generic method and cast each time, but I am worried about the performance overhead... Any suggestions?

-- **EDITED ANSWER**
Based on [Mr Anderson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38529501/2490877), I created a small test program which compares directly setting the value, cached reflection (where FieldInfo's are cached) and the cached multi-type code. I use object inheritance with up to 3 level of inheritance (`ObjectC : ObjectB : ObjectA`).

[Full code is of the example can be found here.](https://eswys.com/StackOverflow/perfTester.zip)

Single iteration of the test gives following output:

```
-------------------------
---      OBJECT A     ---
-------------------------
  Set direct:       0.0036 ms
  Set reflection:   2.319 ms
  Set ref.Emit:     1.8186 ms
  Set Accessor:     4.3622 ms

-------------------------
---      OBJECT B     ---
-------------------------
  Set direct:       0.0004 ms
  Set reflection:   0.1179 ms
  Set ref.Emit:     1.2197 ms
  Set Accessor:     2.8819 ms

-------------------------
---      OBJECT C     ---
-------------------------
  Set direct:       0.0024 ms
  Set reflection:   0.1106 ms
  Set ref.Emit:     1.1577 ms
  Set Accessor:     2.9451 ms
```

Of course, this simply shows the cost of creating the objects - this allows us to measure the offset of creating the cached versions of Reflection and Expressions.

Next, let's run 1.000.000 times:

```
-------------------------
---      OBJECT A     ---
-------------------------
  Set direct:       33.2744 ms
  Set reflection:   1259.9551 ms
  Set ref.Emit:     531.0168 ms
  Set Accessor:     505.5682 ms

-------------------------
---      OBJECT B     ---
-------------------------
  Set direct:       38.7921 ms
  Set reflection:   2584.2972 ms
  Set ref.Emit:     971.773 ms
  Set Accessor:     901.7656 ms

-------------------------
---      OBJECT C     ---
-------------------------
  Set direct:       40.3942 ms
  Set reflection:   3796.3436 ms
  Set ref.Emit:     1510.1819 ms
  Set Accessor:     1469.4459 ms
```

For the sake of completeness: I removed the call to the "set" method to highlight the cost of getting the setter (`FieldInfo` for the reflection method, `Action<object, object>` for the expression case). Here the results:

```
-------------------------
---      OBJECT A     ---
-------------------------
  Set direct:       3.6849 ms
  Set reflection:   44.5447 ms
  Set ref.Emit:     47.1925 ms
  Set Accessor:     49.2954 ms


-------------------------
---      OBJECT B     ---
-------------------------
  Set direct:       4.1016 ms
  Set reflection:   76.6444 ms
  Set ref.Emit:     79.4697 ms
  Set Accessor:     83.3695 ms

-------------------------
---      OBJECT C     ---
-------------------------
  Set direct:       4.2907 ms
  Set reflection:   128.5679 ms
  Set ref.Emit:     126.6639 ms
  Set Accessor:     132.5919 ms
```

NOTE: time increase here is not due to the fact that access times are slower for larger dictionaries (as they have `O(1)` access times), but due to the fact that the number of times we access it is increased (4 times per iteration for `ObjectA`, 8 for `ObjectB`, 12 for `ObjectC`)... As one sees, only the creation offset makes a difference here (which is to be expected).

Bottom line: we did improve performance by a factor of 2 or more, but we're still far away from the direct field set's performance... Retrieving the correct setter in the list represents a good 10% of the time.

I'll try with expression trees in place of Reflection.Emit to see if we can further reduce the gap... Any comment is more than welcome.

***EDIT 2***
I added results using the approach using a generic "Accessor" class as suggested by [Eli Arbel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276083/eli-arbel) on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38538377/2490877).

Comment: "Worried about the performance" doesn't quite cut it. Test it, see if it performs well enough, and decide based on that. I don't see any reason why using a generic method would be worse than your current approach.

Comment: I used to use this approach (expressions), then I discovered `System.Reflection.Emit.DyanamicMethod` is much more straightforward.

Comment: I think the Dynamic runtime caches also this sort of stuff. I don't think it would perform that much slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to support operations on multiple types, your function cache should be indexed by `Type` AND field name (`string`), and the functions should be lazily created. Try this:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, Action<object, object>>> _typeMapper = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, Action<object, object>>>();

public static void Set(object obj, string fieldName, object newValue)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
    }
    Type type = obj.GetType();
    Dictionary<string, Action<object, object>> fieldMapper;
    Action<object, object> action;
    if (_typeMapper.TryGetValue(type, out fieldMapper))
    {
        // entry has been created for this type.
        if (!fieldMapper.TryGetValue(fieldName, out action))
        {
            // method has not been created yet, must build it.
            FieldInfo fld = type.GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (fld == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("No field " + fieldName);
            }
            action = buildSetter(fld);
            fieldMapper.Add(fieldName, action); // add it to method cache for future use.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // -- ADDED CODE: forgot to create the new fieldMapper.....
        fieldMapper = new Dictionary<string, Action<object, object>>();

     // type has not been added yet, so we know method has not been built yet either.
        FieldInfo fld = type.GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (fld == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No field " + fieldName);
        }
        action = buildSetter(fld);
        fieldMapper.Add(fieldName, action); // add it to method cache for future use.
        _typeMapper.Add(type, fieldMapper); // add it to type cache for future use.
    }
    action(obj, newValue); // invoke the method.
}
// this is my preferred setter-builder, feel free to use expressions instead.
private static Action<object, object> buildSetter(FieldInfo fld)
{
    DynamicMethod dyn = new DynamicMethod("set_" + fld, typeof(void), new[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) }, fld.DeclaringType);
    ILGenerator gen = dyn.GetILGenerator();
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, fld.DeclaringType);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    if (fld.FieldType.IsClass)
    {
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, fld.FieldType);
    }
    else
    {
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, fld.FieldType);
    }
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fld);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    return (Action<object, object>)dyn.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<object, object>));
}
```

Otherwise, if you need only do this with one type, your process becomes:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Action<MyType, object>> _mapper = new Dictionary<string, Action<MyType, object>>();

public static void Set(MyType obj, string fieldName, object newValue)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
    }
    Action<MyType, object> action;
    if (!_mapper.TryGetValue(fieldName, out action))
    {
        FieldInfo fld = typeof(MyType).GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (fld == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No field " + fieldName);
        }
        action = buildSetter(fld);
        _mapper.Add(fieldName, action);
    }
    action(obj, newValue); // invoke the method.
}

private static Action<MyType, object> buildSetter(FieldInfo fld)
{
    DynamicMethod dyn = new DynamicMethod("set_" + fld, typeof(void), new[] { typeof(MyType), typeof(object) }, typeof(MyType));
    ILGenerator gen = dyn.GetILGenerator();
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    if (fld.FieldType.IsClass)
    {
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, fld.FieldType);
    }
    else
    {
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, fld.FieldType);
    }
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fld);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    return (Action<MyType, object>)dyn.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<MyType, object>));
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I'll write a little performance test programm to check performances of both and post it here.