# C# FieldInfo reflection alternatives

Tags: c#, reflection, fieldinfo

I am currently using `FieldInfo.GetValue` and `FieldInfo.SetValue` quite a lot in my programm, which is significantly slowing up my programm.

For `PropertyInfo` I use the `GetValueGetter` and `GetValueSetter` methods so I only use reflection once for a given type. For the `FieldInfo`, the methods don't exist.

What is the suggested approach for `FieldInfo`?

EDIT:
I followed [this useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073091/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-delegate-to-get-and-set-values-for-a-fieldinfo) from [CodeCaster's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster) reply. This is a great search direction.

Now the "only" point that I don't get in this answer is how I can cache the getters / setters and re-use them in a generic way, using only the field's name - which is basically what the `SetValue` is doing

```
// generate the cache
Dictionary<string, object> setters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Type t = this.GetType();
foreach (FieldInfo fld in t.GetFields()) {
     MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("CreateSetter");
     MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod( new Type[] {this.GetType(), fld.FieldType});
     setters.Add(fld.Name, genericMethod.Invoke(null, new[] {fld}));
}
// now how would I use these setters?
setters[fld.Name].Invoke(this, new object[] {newValue}); // => doesn't work without cast....
```

Comment: Not using reflection unless you absolutely need it.

Comment: How is the FieldInfo obtained? If you know the name of the field during compile-time, I suggest making a pair of lambda expression for set and get the value.

Comment: @CodeCaster Not a duplicate, at least not of the linked question. Please note that the question in link is about PropertyInfo, this one about FieldInfo. There's a significant difference in these two.

Comment: @Illidan that doesn't matter, the discussion is still the same. Cache the Property|FieldInfo objects, use Reflection.Emit to actually emit the IL that assigns the fields instead of going the reflection way (or use a library that does so) and so on, all of which the OP can use to do further research. See also [Is there a way to create a delegate to get and set values for a FieldInfo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073091/). Enough has been written on this subject already, and one can only select one duplicate. This question is in no way unique, nor well-researched.

Comment: @CodeCaster That's a much better link to help the questioner, thanks.

Comment: instead of us trying to guess what will make things faster you should explain to us why you need to use reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Expression`s to generate faster field accessors. If you want them to work on `Object` rather than the field's concrete type, you'd have to add casts (`Convert`) in the expression.

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class FieldAccessor
{
    private static readonly ParameterExpression fieldParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    private static readonly ParameterExpression ownerParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));

    public FieldAccessor(Type type, string fieldName)
    {
        var field = type.GetField(fieldName,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (field == null) throw new ArgumentException();

        var fieldExpression = Expression.Field(
            Expression.Convert(ownerParameter, type), field);

        Get = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(
            Expression.Convert(fieldExpression, typeof(object)),
            ownerParameter).Compile();

        Set = Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(
            Expression.Assign(fieldExpression,
                Expression.Convert(fieldParameter, field.FieldType)), 
            ownerParameter, fieldParameter).Compile();
    }

    public Func<object, object> Get { get; }

    public Action<object, object> Set { get; }
}
```

Usage:

```
class M
{
    private string s;
}

var accessors = new Dictionary<string, FieldAccessor>();

// expensive - you should do this only once
accessors.Add("s", new FieldAccessor(typeof(M), "s"));

var m = new M();
accessors["s"].Set(m, "Foo");
var value = accessors["s"].Get(m);
```

Comment: I tried to compile your example.  It appears the types are missing from the static readonly fields.   I tried to use "Expression", but then the compiler could not resolve the call to Expression.Lambda() with those parameters.  OK.  So "ParameterExpression" is what is needed.

Comment: Also had to add private set; for "Get" and "Set".  Or is that a new C# 6.0 syntax?  Implied private set?