# Blazor : is it possible to bind a generic item to a property by its name using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, binding, blazor

I'm trying to get a generic editor template using Blazor that binds to properties found by reflection as follows :

```
@typeparam TItem

@foreach (var propertyName in FieldsList) {
    <div>
        <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="@getBindProperty(propertyName)" />
    </div>
}

@functions {
    [Parameter]
    public TItem ItemEditModel { get; set; }

    public string[] FieldsList {
        get {
            // get all properties decorated with some custom attribute...
            return typeof(TItem).GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(MyCustomAttribute))).Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
        }
    }

    public string getBindProperty(string propName) {
        return string.Format("{0}.{1}", nameof(ItemEditModel), propName);
    }
}
```

The above is not accepted as  *The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer*.

So I cannot bind to a property by its name, so I went on trying other syntax like

```
<InputText id="name" @bind-Value="ItemEditModel.propertyName" />
```

This is not accepted either as *TItem does not contain a definition of 'propertyName'*.

Well all the above make sense - but the key question - is there anything to be done about it, or is it impossible to bind a control to a property by its name?

**BONUS QUESTION:**
If it is actually possible to do this, is there a way to make a switch depending on the property type (typically, only primitive types like ´string´, ´DateTime´, ´int´, ´double´, ´bool´...)?

Answer (score 4):

If you use InputText Blazor's component you should wrap it with the EditForm Blazor's component.

An alternative way to do it could be probably as follows:

```
    @typeparam TItem

    @foreach (var propertyName in FieldsList)
    {
       <div>
          <input @bind="PropertyVars[propertyName]" />
       </div>
    }

    <button type="button" @onclick="OnSubmit">Reset</button>

    @code {
        [Parameter]
        public TItem ItemEditModel { get; set; }

       public Dictionary<string, string> PropertyVars { get; set; } = new 
     Dictionary<string, string>();

   protected override void OnInitialized()
   {
     foreach (var propertyName in FieldsList)
     {
        var propertyInfo = ItemEditModel.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        PropertyVars.Add(propertyName, 
        propertyInfo?.GetValue(ItemEditModel).ToString());
     }

  }

  public string[] FieldsList
  {
    get
    {
        return typeof(TItem).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
    }
  }

  private void OnSubmit()
  {
    var tt = PropertyVars;

    foreach (var propertyName in FieldsList)
    {
        var propertyInfo = ItemEditModel.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

        var uu = PropertyVars[propertyName].GetType();

        if (uu == propertyInfo?.PropertyType)
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(ItemEditModel, 
            Convert.ChangeType(PropertyVars[propertyName], propertyInfo.PropertyType),
            null);
        }

    }

    var yy = ItemEditModel;
 }
}
```

Comment: well, that's actually creating a "buffer" of the values to be stored/retrieved after completion, which is of course a decent way to do it... Any idea if this is at all possible to make a DIRECT bind to the original object?

Comment: Ok, based on your anser, I added a property indexor to the base class that returns the same as the above - and this got the whole magic to work. THANKS for the idea!

Comment: Just sharing another useful resource here, to give credits to a very useful trick here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344620/easy-creation-of-properties-that-support-indexing-in-c-sharp

Comment: @neggenbe You are welcome. Glad to help and thanks for the link, very helpfull

Comment: @neggenbe Don't suppose you'd like to answer your own question with what you ended up with? I find myself trying to do something similar.

Comment: @Kruft I post the solution just below to wrap up the different elements!

Comment: if any value is null then you need to PropertyVars.Add(propertyName,
propertyInfo?.GetValue(ItemEditModel)?.ToString() ?? ""); instead of  PropertyVars.Add(propertyName, 
        propertyInfo?.GetValue(ItemEditModel).ToString());

Answer (score 1):

To wrap up the solution I ended up with:

1. I created indexed property class wrappers that allow me to access values (note that I created 2 additional ones that are readonly and writeonly, in case it helps)

   ```
    public class IndexedProperty<TIndex, TValue> {
        readonly Action<TIndex, TValue> SetAction;
        readonly Func<TIndex, TValue> GetFunc;

        public IndexedProperty(Func<TIndex, TValue> getFunc, Action<TIndex, TValue> setAction) {
          this.GetFunc = getFunc;
          this.SetAction = setAction;
        }
        public TValue this[TIndex i] {
          get {
            return GetFunc(i);
          }
          set {
            SetAction(i, value);
          }
        }
      }


      public class ReadOnlyIndexedProperty<TIndex, TValue> {
            readonly Func<TIndex, TValue> GetFunc;

        public ReadOnlyIndexedProperty(Func<TIndex, TValue> getFunc) {
          this.GetFunc = getFunc;
        }

        public TValue this[TIndex i] {
          get {
            return GetFunc(i);
          }
        }
      }


      public class WriteOnlyIndexedProperty<TIndex, TValue> {
        readonly Action<TIndex, TValue> SetAction;

        public WriteOnlyIndexedProperty(Action<TIndex, TValue> setAction) {
          this.SetAction = setAction;
        }

        public TValue this[TIndex i] {
          set {
            SetAction(i, value);
          }
        }
      }
   ```
2. I created a "BindableBase" object that all my objects inherit from, in wich I added the index property :

   ```
   IndexedProperty<string, string> _strValues;
   [JsonIgnore]
   public IndexedProperty<string, string> StrValues {
     get {
       if (_strValues == null) {
         _strValues = new IndexedProperty<string, string>(GetStrValue, SetStrValue);
       }
       return _strValues;
     }
   }

   private string GetStrValue(string propName) {
     // use reflection here to get the property value as string
     // --- NOTE: beware of performance here I suggest you take a look at related link
   }

   private void SetStrValue(string propName, string value) {
     // use reflection here to SET the property value from string
     // --- NOTE: beware of performance here I suggest you take a look at related link
   }
   ```

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38527266/field-getter-setter-with-expression-tree-in-base-class) if performance is of matter to you!

3. In my form, I bind using the indexed properties as follows :

   ```
   @foreach (var propertyName in FieldsList) {
       <div>
           <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="@myContextObject.StrValues[propertyName]" />
       </div>
   }
   ```

Credits to @copycar_am and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344620/easy-creation-of-properties-that-support-indexing-in-c-sharp).

Comment: PS: sorry for formatting, can't get the code to be detected properly...